# How do I setup multiple suites in Reprepro?

Tags: apt, reprepro

I want a private apt repository for stable and unstable lucid packages.  I keep getting an error when I try to include a debian.

```
Multiple distributions with the common codename: 'lucid'!
First was in ./conf/distributions line 1 to 8, another in lines 10 to 17There have been errors!
```

I'm using this config file.

```
Origin: Stable Repository
Label: Stable Repository
Suite: stable
Codename: lucid
Architectures: i386 amd64
Components: main non-free
Description: Stable Repository
SignWith: yes

Origin: Unstable Repository
Label: Unstable Repository
Suite: unstable
Codename: lucid
Architectures: i386 amd64
Components: main non-free
Description: Unstable Repository
SignWith: yes
```

What's wrong with my config file?

Answer (score 5):

Like the error message says, you have the same codename in both suites, which isn't possible. You would have to call the second one something like "lucid-unstable". This is similar to what the official repo does with lucid-updates, lucid-proposed, lucid-backports, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I never figured this out with reprepro, but I did discover Freight, which makes debian repository management much easier than with reprepro.

https://github.com/rcrowley/freight

Comment: freight does not support suite tag in metadata which I also was looking for. Even years later freight still does not support removing or copying deps so we still use reprepo